# Bind9 Server Default NXDOMAIN Response

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have been searching the internet about this for a while and did not seem to be able to find a solution:
Is it possible to configure Bind9 in a way that it returns a default ("The page you are looking for does not exist"-kind-of) IP when it receives a request to a nonexistant domain?

For example asdfsdfsdafsdf.com (or any not registered domain) would not return NXDOMAIN, but rather a default IP Address redirecting to this "Address not found"-page.

Comment: You *could* - several ISPs do this (Windstream is mine, and they do, redirecting all NXDOMAINS to their search page).  But ... it is considered to be breaking DNS - a domain that doesn't exist SHOULD return the NXDOMAIN.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking .

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe BIND has any functionality that can do this. RPZ is probably the feature that comes the closest, but has no trigger for NXDOMAIN.

That said, what you are asking for is more likely just causing problems for the users;  typically any benefit is rather entirely the service provider's, since they get to show their ads or whatever their goal is. (Probably related to why this practice is both frowned upon at large and not a feature implemented in BIND.)

The more idealistic issues aside, some concrete technical problems that arise for users are obvious:

- It's severely HTTP-in-a-browser-used-by-a-human centric.

  - It falls apart with HTTPS, causing confusion.
  - It causes great confusion with programmatic HTTP access.
  - It causes great confusion with applications/protocols not handled by your service (likely anything but HTTP).
- It breaks already on the DNS level with DNSSEC.

  - You are lying in the responses, this is exactly what DNSSEC is meant to catch.